# ERROR in compiling C++ Boost iostream library

Tags: c++, boost

I am using the boost library to decompress a compressed file. However, when I compile the project using CMake I get the following error during compilation. The snippet is as below.

### Include Directories

```
include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
```

### Code Snippet

```
  ifstream infile;
  boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> inbuf;
  inbuf.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
  inbuf.push(infile);
```

### CmakeList

```
g++ Version 4.8.5 & g++ 7.3.1 (Same error with both tries)
Using standard 17
find_package(Boost 1.67.0)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(<project-name> ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

### Compilation Error

```
/usr/local/include/boost/iostreams/detail/access_control.hpp: In constructor ‘boost::iostreams::detail::pub_<U>::pub_(V)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/iostreams/detail/access_control.hpp:43:42: error: class ‘boost::iostreams::detail::pub_<U>’ does not have any field named ‘v’
         template<typename V> pub_(V v) : U(v) { }

/usr/local/include/boost/iostreams/detail/access_control.hpp:43:49: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
         template<typename V> pub_(V v) : U(v) { }
```

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve] and the exact compiler version and command line used to invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
#define _TURN_OFF_PLATFORM_STRING
```

It may be due to conflict with some macros defined in other included libraries.

You can try switching to Boost 1.72.0 if this doesn't work with the latest g++ version (9.2.0). Recheck your compiler flags and if the problem still persists do make a comment with sufficient code to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. One caveat that the instruction #define _TURN_OFF_PLATFORM_STRING needs to be added at the top most (first line) of a .h/.cpp file where the libraries under discussion are being imported.